# android:layout_alignParentBottom is ignored when used without explicit layout height as a row in ListView

Tags: android, layout

When I use a `RelativeLayout` with either `fill_parent` or `wrap_content` as height and an element which specifies: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` it is ignored and it is aligned at the top. Setting the height of the `RelativeLayout` to an explicit value makes it work. Any clues?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Android itself, see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1394.

I worked around it by wrapping my `RelativeLayout` in a `FrameLayout` and putting my bottom aligned view as a children of the `FrameLayout` with `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`. This hinders you from referencing it from within the `RelativeLayout` so you'll have to work around that (for example using margins).

If anyone has a better workaround, please share.

Comment: I had the same problem and it seems to be because of that bug indeed. It's fixed in Froyo but not in Eclair.

Comment: Here is an workaround, i've just published http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1394#c16

Answer (score 3):

When you inflate the layout, use `inflate(R.layout.whatever, parent, false)`, where `parent` is the `ListView`. If you don't do that (e.g., you pass `null` for the parent), `RelativeLayout` gets strange in list rows.

Comment: Still can't get it to work. I'm using CursorAdapter and in newView() I now have: View v = inflater.inflate(ROW_RESOURCE, postList, false);

Comment: Here's a project from one my books that uses `RelativeLayouts` in rows: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot/ -- see if that gives you any clues as to where things may be going wrong for you.

Comment: Seems to be this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1394. Not fixed on 1.6. Setting a fixed height is not really an option as the height needs to be variable. Any good workarounds? Or am I forced to create may own custom layout ;C

Comment: Can you achieve your visual goal with nested `LinearLayouts`?

Comment: Not really, too complex. I'm trying to wrap the bottom aligned view in different layouts now to see if I can work around it. Might go to sleep and continue tomorrow instead tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the proper alignment by specifying the problematic TextView with:

```
android:id="@+id/must_be_bottom_left"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_below="@id/xxx"
```

where `xxx` was the id of a `TextView` that has `android:layout_below="@id/yyy"`

and `yyy` is a `TextView` that is always above both `xxx` and `must_be_bottom_left`.

The contents of my list items can vary so that sometimes the "xxx" `TextView` is `View.GONE`, but even then the layout works as expected.

I don't know how fragile or merely seredipidous this work-around is.  I am using Android 1.6 and I haven't tested it for forward compatability.

Answer (score 0):

My hack for this andriod bug:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp=(ViewGroup.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
lp.height=view.getContentHeight();//hack for android bug about ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT and android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" on landscape orientation
view.requestLayout();
act.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```