# Positioning button on bottom of screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to make a very simple screen with a button at the bottom of the screen (and nothing else at this point) using the xml below.  It looks fine in Android Studio but when I run it on my phone the button is not visible (probably outside the screen).  Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:text="Send"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android:layout\_alignParentBottom is ignored when used without explicit layout height as a row in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520418/androidlayout-alignparentbottom-is-ignored-when-used-without-explicit-layout-he)

Comment: Are you using the layout by calling `setContentView(layoutResourceId)` in the `onCreate()`-method of an `Activity`-class?

Comment: This looks correct, is there wrapping xml ?

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer a `LinearLayout`, using `layout_gravity="bottom"` attribute will set it to the bottom of the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:text="Send"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity_layout="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```